# Sum the extracted matching node values and transfer the same to the next response

Tags: groovy, soapui

We are using the opensource SoapUI and am trying to get some calculation out of a response.

This is a sample response that we are getting out of a request

```
<Response>
  <PropertyDef>
    <Property1>
        <e>
            <Name>Prop1-1</Name>
            <ID>1</ID>
        </e>
        <e> 
            <Name>Prop1-2</Name>
            <ID>2</ID>
        </e>
    </Property1>
    <Property2>
        <e>
            <Name>Prop2-1</Name>
            <ID>11</ID>
        </e>
        <e> 
            <Name>Prop2-2</Name>
            <ID>22</ID>
        </e>
    </Property2>
  </PropertyDef>
  <Propertyvalues>
   <e>
     <value1>3.0</value1>
      <references>
        <prop1>1</prop1>
        <prop2>11</prop2>
      </references>
      <value2>5</value2>
    </e>
    <e>
     <value1>4.0</value1>
      <references>
        <prop1>1</prop1>
        <prop2>22</prop2>
      </references>
      <value2>4</value2>
    </e>
    <e>
     <value1>6.0</value1>
      <references>
        <prop1>2</prop1>
        <prop2>11</prop2>
      </references>
      <value2>1</value2>
    </e>
  </Propertyvalues>

</Response>
```

Based on this response, lets say I need to find all property values which have the prop2 value of 11. That would have two property values

```
<e>
      <value1>3.0</value1>
      <references>
        <prop1>1</prop1>
        <prop2>11</prop2>
      </references>
      <value2>5</value2>
</e>
<e>
      <value1>6.0</value1>
      <references>
        <prop1>2</prop1>
        <prop2>11</prop2>
      </references>
      <value2>1</value2>
</e>
```

Now we need to get the sum of value1s in this set and set it to a property to be used in a different request. In this example I would need to get 6 + 3 = 9 and be set to the property based on the response. Is there a way to do that please ?

Any help  is appreciated

Comment: Have you check the solution? appreciate if you can accept it as solution if it has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use below `Script Assertion` for the same REST request. Comments in-line:

```groovy
//Define the following ; edit if required.
def expectedProp2Value = 11
def expectedKeyName = 'prop2'
def keyNameToSum = 'value1'

//Pass the response to parseText method
def pxml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)

//Find all matching element e; 
def alles = pxml.'**'.findAll{it.name() ==  expectedKeyName && it == expectedProp2Value }*.parent()*.parent()
//Sum the values
def result = alles.collect{ it."$keyNameToSum".text() as float }.sum()
log.info "Sum of the values : $result"


//If you want to use the above sum in the next request; use below
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('SUM', result.toString())
```

You can try the same online <kbd>[Demo](http://ideone.com/Rk6gdz)</kbd>  (till summation part, rest is specific to soapui)

In the next request, use below *property expansion* where the above **SUM** is needed. For example:

`<sum>${#TestCase#SUM}</sum>`